# Can a Rust async function work without importing the Future trait?

Tags: rust, future

In the code below, I did not import the `Future` trait:

```
async fn hello_world() {
    println!("hello, world!");
}

fn main() {
    let future = hello_world(); 
}
```

and yet it still compiles. However it won't print anything.

According to [*why async fn in traits are hard*](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/10/26/async-fn-in-traits-are-hard/):

> ```
> impl MyDatabase {
>     async fn get_user(&self) -> User {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This would get desugared to something similar to:
>
> ```
> impl MyDatabase {
>     fn get_user(&self) -> impl Future<Output = User> + '_ {
>         ... 
>     }
> }
> ```

How can this desugaring be done if no `Future` trait is imported? More importantly, why is the `Future` trait not defined in Rust itself, but instead is in a crate?

Comment: The phrase "to something similar to" is meant to signal that the desugaring shown is simplified for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can this desugar be done if no `Future` trait is imported?

The compiler desugars to the fully-qualified path: `core::future::Future`.

> why is the `Future` trait not defined in Rust itself, but instead is in a crate?

It *is* in the standard library: [`std::future::Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html). The Rust API documentation has a search function; I encourage you to become familiar with it.

The `Future` trait *was* defined in the futures crate before it was added to the standard library, much like the `Stream` trait. Those both exist in the standard library now.

Comment: Why `AsyncWrite` and `AsyncRead` are not defined in the core::future but it is in the futures::future crate?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs the ecosystem has not yet agreed on what it should look like. [`Future` had a RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2592-futures.html), [`Stream` had a RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2996-async-stream.html). I expect that every trait like that will need a separate RFC.